# Update .spcolor file doesn't reflect on the site - Sharepoint 2013 foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, theme

I have Sharepoint 2013 Foundation installed.
I'm following this article to modify/create composed look:
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Step-by-Step-Create-a-SharePoint-2013-Composed-Look.aspx

But I'm having problem changing the .spcolor

In _catalogs/theme/15/ folder, I have copied an existing (Palette010.spcolor) to test.spcolor.
I went to "change the look" and selected any composed look, and changed the colors to the one I have just created.
Then I went to "Site Settings" -> "Composed look", and I can see the current is using the test.spcolor file.

Then I went to SP Designer, and edited the test.spcolor file. I modified:

```
<s:color name="SiteTitle" value="20cbef00" />
<s:color name="WebPartHeading" value="20cbef00" />
```

but when I refresh my site (/SitePages/Home.aspx), nothing has changed.

The only thing I have noticed is there is a blue "info" icon in front of the test.spcolor file in SPD. (don't have enough reputation to post screenshot..:( )

Anyone know where have I done wrong..? Thanks!!

Comment: The changes to an existing color palette file isn't applied until you re-apply the composed look. Navigate to site Settings - Look and Feel - change the look - click on current theme (or appropriate theme) and re-apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think editing the file with SharePoint Designer has made it [unghosted (customized)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2007/11/03/sharepoint-terms-ghosted-unghosted-and-reghosted.aspx). SharePoint will not use it for existing sites in this case.

You should probably use [SharePoint Color Palette tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182) to develop your themes, and once ready upload as described in your link.

There are different techniques for Ghosting items again, you can google it. But I would create a new .spcolor file because it will be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that color palette tool but as a developer I would like to know how to do it in the raw code. Do you have that info?